# Grunt - Copy specific file without usemin

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I would like to copy specific coffeescript file (which is not included in the `<!-- build:js({.tmp, app}) -->` section in my `index.html`) to for example `dist/scripts` directory.

I tried with (`Gruntfile.js`):

```
    copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [
            // ...
            {
                expand: true,
                cwd: './tmp/scripts/polyfill',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/polyfill',
                src: [
                    '*'
                ]
            }]
        }
    },
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This worked:

```
{
    expand: true,
    cwd: '.tmp/scripts/polyfill',
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/polyfill',
    src: [
        'polyfill.js'
    ]
}
```

My approach was good, however it contained a typo: `./tmp` - it should be `.tmp`.

Comment: This does, however, copy all `.js` files instead of a specific one.

Comment: I could just pass `polyfill.js` instead of `*.js`

Answer (score 1):

If you just have one single file you want to copy over, you can use the simpler grunt syntax:

```
copy: {
    dist: {
        files: [{
            '.tmp/scripts/polyfill/myfile.js': '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/polyfill/myfile.js'
        }]
    }
}
```

Also the name of the temporary folder is `.tmp`, not just `tmp`.

Comment: Didn't work, however you've highlighted a typo in my code: `./tmp`. :)